# React-Router Lifecycle mixin - depreacted? What to use instead for confirming navigation in v1.0.3?

Tags: react-router

I'm running react-router 1.0.3

My aim is to intercept a user navigating away from a page and put up the standard browser confirm dialog.

On the Github page [1] the page says that the LifeCycle mixin is deprecated. (It looks like I could use it but perhaps should not if it is being deprecated).

From this page [2] it appears that in v.2 one can use the new feature router.setRouteLeaveHook (which looks good). This will set up listenBeforeLeavingRoute for you (and unbind it).

So: for version 1.0.3 what should I use to put a hook into the leavepage transition event? It looks like not the LifeCycle mixin. But setRouteLeaveHook is not yet available. I should perhaps implement it manually; like this: @props.history.listenBeforeLeavingRoute(@props.route, callback)? If I do do I need to manually remove the listener in componentWillUnmount? (I believe so).

Also - is v 2.0.0 in production? if I just run npm install I get version 1.0.3

(React-Router is great but the problem is that the docs always seem to be out of synch with the current release. The producers of it don't seem to see documentation as an integral part of the software; which, to my mind it is).

1. https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md
2. https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#mixins-are-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of the React Router.

Let me answer your question first. The best way to get information about the React Router v1.0.x is [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/1.0.x) (it's a 1.0.x branch). And there, you can find bunch of very useful examples, the one you are looking for is the [`transitions` example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/examples/transitions/app.js).

If you are using ES6 classes, then you can't use mixins and so you need to make use of `history`, and you can find the example of Confirming Navigation in the [rackt/history repo](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/ConfirmingNavigation.md).

Thanks for your feedback on the docs. We are not ignoring this topic, and we know it's an issue. Ryan is working on the tutorial (see a sneak peek [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS0OiEwf4rM)), and we are in the process of [making the docs better](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2933).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. On the master docs - https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md - it says that the LifeCycle Mixin is being deprecated. So I had a  look at the code and  because of the issue of possible deprecation I've implemented manually - just doing what it does - with listenBeforeLeavingRoute in componentDidMount. Thanks for the heads-up on the docs and the video tut. Yes; flagging up the version the docs relate to would help people like me from reading the wrong ones!

Comment: Also I find the upgrade guides very useful, have a look at them too. Read more about the [Routers future](https://medium.com/rackt-and-roll/react-router-s-future-c026c0f2874f). Now the changes and upgrades are going to be much better than before. So a lot of these issues should be eliminated

Comment: @knowbody I understand that the docs are being worked on, but I imagine it would take the same amount of time to insert your SO answer into https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/docs/ConfirmingNavigation.md than it took for you to post your answer here. I think it would save a lot of developers much time and frustration.

Comment: @WalterRoman I'll try to get better at it. I don't have as much time as I would like to have to do those things.

Comment: @knowbody It's as easy as clicking a button now: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/pull/3142